# How do I execute a function in a certain way after importing it in another python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a function that returns a list of length of random numbers from 0 to 9.

```
import random

def makeList():
    y=[]
    n=int(raw_input("Enter number"))

    for x in range(0,n):
        x=random.randint(0,9)
        y.append(x)
    print y

def main():
    makeList()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now i am creating another python file called main.py and importing this function
this is the code i wrote in main.py . The name of the file is myFunc.

```
from myFuncs import makeList
makeList()
```

Now, 
    I want to create a list of ( say 10 random numbers.) what should i write inside the main.py file to achieve this ?

Comment: `myList = makeList()`?

Comment: in the above  "makelist" function.. i want to add  10 in the raw_input by writing certain code in the main.py file. how could i achieve that?

Comment: oh, my apologies. I mis-read your question. You need to return `y` instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `print y` to `return y` in the first file. (and `print(makeList())` under `main()`)

In the new file, `new_list = makeList()`

then new_list is that generated list.

Edit: More pythonic version

**File 1**

```
import random

def make_list(length=10):
    return [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(length)]

def main():
    amount = int(raw_input("Enter number"))
    print(make_list(amount))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**File 2**

```
from myFuncs import make_list

new_list = make_list()
print(new_list) # will be default 10
```

**--**

If you want to keep the input in that same function it is possible, here is one way:

```
def make_list(length=0):
    if not length:
        length= int(raw_input("Enter number"))    
    return [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(length)]

def main():
    print(make_list())
```

Then specify `make_list(10)` in the second file

Comment: sorry if i was not able to explain well but my desire is   to write a code in the File 2  that will print 10 random numbers without having to input in the console the " 10"

Comment: your code still makes me type 10  as it asks me to "enter number" .. but i want the program to execute itself leaving file 1 alone.... writing some thing in file 2 only

Comment: you still edited file 1 rite? Leave file 1 alone... lets say you need file 1 independently .. and with file 2 you should be able to print 10 random numbers .. is it possible?

Comment: @gurkha_dawg without removing the `raw_input` line from file 1 it will always ask for it. I know no way of disabling that without modifying that file

Comment: makeList function has   n=int(raw_input("Enter number"))  .. can we say that n=10 in file 2

Comment: No, you can't modify a function's code from another module. You'd have to just reimplement it if you can't modify the first one.

Comment: in main.py  my goal is to use makeList to create a list with 10 numbers.